# WiFi hotspot keeps shutting off automatically on vivo V7

Tags: wifi-hotspot, vivo

The WiFi hotspot on vivo V7 turns off on its own. I can't even see any additional settings.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Tap on Hotspot Configuration and check whether there's any option to set timeout or time limit or connection time. Timeout have many options like 10 mins, 30 minutes, 1 hour, unlimited etc. If you set unlimited, WiFi will continue until you turn off hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is to keep a device connected. The device turns off the Hotspot when it sees no device using it for over 2 minutes.

This is certainly a very strict timeframe. Anyhow, the setting to automatically close Hotspot is baked into the system and as such, it will not be possible to override it.